# input type radio + text area in a php script

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have a problem that I don't really know how to fix it since I couldn't find a solution online.
I have a simple html form with some radio buttons to have multiple choice, here is my index.html

```
        <form action="process.php" method="POST">

         <fieldset>         
    <legend><font color="blue">Select your favorite color:</font></legend>           
 <input type="radio" name="color" value="Blue"/>Blue.<br/>          
 <input type="radio" name="color" value="Red"/>Red<br/>             
 <input type="radio" name="color" value="Green"/>Green<br/>
        </fieldset>
```

here is my process.php

```
if(isset($_POST['color'])){

    $color = $_POST['color'];

        echo ("Your favorite color is: </br>" .$color);
}

else{

        echo ("You didn't select any color!");

}
```

Now I want to add another choice on the html form but this must be a textarea
so the code should look like this:

```
         <fieldset>         
    <legend><font color="blue">Select your favorite color:</font></legend>           
 <input type="radio" name="color" value="Blue"/>Blue.<br/>          
 <input type="radio" name="color" value="Red"/>Red<br/>             
 <input type="radio" name="color" value="Green"/>Green<br/>
 <input type="textarea" name="color" placerholder="write your favorite color">
        </fieldset>
```

The problem is if the user select the option "Green" which is in a radio button the php script won't see it and it will leave the $color in php blank. So my output is basically:
Your favorite color is: [blank space]. Even if I don't select any radio button and my text area is empthy, I get the same result. The only time it give me a right output is when I type in the textarea something.
Any solution? Thanks in advice

Comment: Use a different name for the textarea …?

Comment: as @misorude says: use a different name. then, use an if to say if no radio button selected look for the textarea value

Comment: @LelioFaieta This sound like a good idea, i need to look up how to do it (i just started learning the basic stuff). Thanks!

Comment: `<input type="textarea"` is not valid HTML. `<textarea></textarea>` is. And `placerholder` should be `placeholder`

Comment: @kerbholz input type it's working for me and the placeholder i just made a type here :P

Comment: That won't render a `textarea`  but an `input` though.

Comment: Ah gotcha, Thanks @kerbholz

Answer (score 0):

change name of your textarea and get description as below . and to use textarea you should use

```
 if(isset($_POST['color'])){

    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

        echo ("Your favorite color is: </br>" .$color);
}

else{

        echo ("You didn't select any color!");

}
```

HTML Code

```
 <fieldset>         
    <legend><font color="blue">Select your favorite color:</font></legend>           
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="Blue"/>Blue.<br/>          
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="Red"/>Red<br/>             
    <input type="radio" name="color" value="Green"/>Green<br/>
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="write your favorite color"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using two else if in my php code:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['color'])){

    $color = $_POST['color'];

        echo ("Your favorite color is: </br>" .$color);
}
else if (empty($_POST['description'])) {

    echo ("You did't select any color!");

}
else if (isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $description = $_POST['description'];

    echo ("Your favorite color is: </br>" .$description);

}

else{

        echo ("You didn't select any color!");

}
?>
```

Thanks to everyone for helping!